# Indentation of child items underneath checked parent item?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, gitlab-wiki

I'm facing an issue with Asciidoc rendering in a GitLab WIKI. I have a nested list like this:

```
.Title
* [x] This is a checked item
** This is a child item
** this is another child item
```

The child items get the correct mark of their corresponding level but the indentation is wrong. The items are aligned all the way to the left with no indentation whatsoever.

Normal nested bullet lists look as expected. It only happens with child items of checklist items. I'm wondering if this is a bug in the renderer or intended behavior.

How can I adjust the indentation of the respective levels so that it looks the way I want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known error in Asciidoctor 2.0.15 an earlier and will be fixed in 2.0.16 (not released yet); see [asciidoctor/asciidoctor#2550](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/2550) for details.

To use this fix in your local setup, you could consider taking the CSS from the issue mentioned above and include it to your local setup as extra CSS.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the answer! That does indeed help a lot.